# Why was my (topology) question closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, on-hold-questions

[Show that a matrix has strictly positive real eigenvalues topology exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556006/show-that-a-matrix-has-strictly-positive-real-eigenvalues-topology-exercise)

I don't understand, is the question too trivial? It's always very hard to know whether a question I ask will be well received or not.

Edit: Thank you for the feedback. I have edited my question to reflect the suggestions.

Comment: The selected close reason was "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level." Adding some context should get it reopened soon.

Comment: There is no question in your linked post.

Comment: @JohnMa the strange thing (to me) is that the question does ask about $M$. I have double checked..

Comment: The question has several issues. One of them, which is easy to fix, is that there is no question, only a command ("Show that...").  Moreover, why are you at the same time asking how to solve the question, and telling us how to do it ("By considering the map...").  Beyond that, though, there are two issues. The first is that the question shows no effort - you have not described any attempts or progress you have made. The second is that the question shows no context - where did the question arise, and why is it of interest? As it stands, the question looks very much like a textbook exercise.

Comment: @CarlMummert I addressed some of your points. I have no attempt to show because I don't understand the question. In my question I am now asking for a careful explanation...